# 21.10 Keyboard shortcut ctrl + shift + alt + up settings are not preserved

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, shortcut-keys, 21.10

In Ubuntu 21.04, I disabled keyboard shortcuts `ctrl+shift+alt+UpArrow` and `+DownArrow` because they conflicted with my IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts.

After upgrading to 21.10, my settings are gone.
Also new Settings->Keyboard->Customize Keyboard menu is horrible.

Here is the problem:

- Open intelJ press `ctrl+shift+alt+UpArrow` nothing happens
- Settings->Keyboard->Customize Keyboard
- Set custom shortcut to `ctrl+shift+alt+UpArrow`
- Remove custom shortcut
- Go back to InteliJ and press `ctrl+shift+alt+UpArrow` - works as expected
- Reboot - the problem is back.

What do I need to do to make the shortcuts stick?

Comment: I just tried dconf editor to set "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up" to default and back to changed value and it looks like it is working for now. I'll leave the question open if anyone comes up with an explanation or a better idea.

Comment: Just edit this key to set it to a blank value (or a different key) - that is your solution. Feel free to write up as an answer, and accept your own answer. That is fine here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, in the end, was to use `dconf editor` to set the key to the default value and then set it back to the expected value.